# using QNetworkAccessManager GET multiple times

Tags: c++, qt, networking

I am writing an application to request a web page at equal intervals in order to get any changes in it (to check whether new data is received). here how i did it.

```
 private:

 QNetworkReply *r;
 QNetworkAccessManager *m;
 QNetworkRequest request;
 QTimer *timer;
```

in the constructor ,

```
m = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
timer = new QTimer(this);
connect(r , SIGNAL(readyRead()), this , SLOT(readit()));
connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
timer->start(1000);
```

readit function,

```
void MainWindow::readit(){
QString st;
st=r->readAll();
m->deleteResource(request);
ui->textBrowser->append(st);
}
```

update function,

```
void MainWindow::update()
{
 request.setUrl(QUrl("http://localhost/test/default.php"));
 r = m->get(request);
}
```

my problem is `m->get(request)` gets the request at its first call only, when it is called again it does nothing. I did several experiments but end up with no success results. i changed the second request to another web page using a button click but it did nothing too.

So I need help from an expert how to update the get request and get new reply multiple times.

and also i want to know am i doing a correct thing or is there mo reliable methods to get data on data change from the server than checking for the website at regular intervals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see following problems:

1. `readyRead` fires an arbitrary number of times per request - including zero times (!), but you treat it as if it fired exactly once. Use the `finished` signal, which is does what you want: fires once, no more, no less.
2. The `update` slot doesn't connect any slots to the request.

Comment: I changed the `readyRead` signal to `finished` signal and it didn't work either. I cant understand what the second reply means. in update I have updated the get request, now when its finished signal fires doesn't it trig the `readit` function. am i doing anything wrong, please explain.

Comment: Ok finally I got it, I need to connect the signal to the specific slot within that function also. It worked. thanks a lot. I wouldn't have figure out it alone. thanks a lot.... :)