# Multiple requests using QNetworkAccessManager qt

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyqt5, qtnetwork

I would like to send multiple POST requests using single `QNetworkAccessManager`, but it works only once. The second and further requests got an empty reply.
I know I can use multiple instances of manager, but I read, that it's an architectural flaw.
I have also found this: [using QNetworkAccessManager GET multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29683368/using-qnetworkaccessmanager-get-multiple-times), but I do not understand the eventual solution.
Here's my code:

```
class Networker(QObject):

    gotResponse = pyqtSignal(str)

    def proc(self, reply):
        s = bytes(reply.readAll()).decode('utf-8')
        self.gotResponse.emit(s)


    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Networker, self).__init__(parent)
        self.manager = QNetworkAccessManager()



    def send(self):
        req = QNetworkRequest(QUrl("http://127.0.0.1:8000/"))
        req.setHeader(QNetworkRequest.ContentTypeHeader, "text/json;charset=utf-8")

        data = QByteArray('{"id":1}')

        self.manager.finished.connect(self.proc)
        self.manager.post(req, data)
```

Main (imports excluded):

```
def main():

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    n = Networker(app)
    w = QtWidgets.QWidget()


    w.setWindowTitle("main")

    layout = QBoxLayout(QBoxLayout.LeftToRight, w)

    l1 = QTextEdit("Result", w)
    l1.resize(300, 600)
    n.gotResponse.connect(l1.setText)
    layout.addWidget(l1)
    w.show()

    l2 = QTextEdit("Idle", w)
    l2.resize(250, 600)

    layout.addWidget(l2)
    w.resize(500, 600)

    btn = QPushButton("Send", w)
    layout.addWidget(btn)   
    btn.clicked.connect(n.send)         
    w.show()





    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: This isn't a complete test case to demonstrate the problem. Please show how you invoke those multiple requests. We need to see a complete program, not just a snippet.

Comment: Using QNetworkReply is the optimal solution. As detailed in the post you referred.

Comment: I think I use QNetworkReply the same way it is used in the referred post. Actually, I was going to use no signals, but I encountered a problem getting the asynchronous reply.